# 404 Not Found Error on Firebase HTTP Post Request ("Cannot Post")

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

Been stuck on this issue for several days now: I’m trying to write a firebase cloud function that updates a document in a firestore collection, based on a HTTP post trigger. I’ve deployed my firebase function but when I hit the url and post data to it, I keep getting a 404 message. I’ve tried triggering it using both postman and curl, but I’m getting the same “404 Not Found” error.

This is the error message:

```
    Error



     <pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
```

This is the cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// upload each landbot consultation to users' firestore collection

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/uploadConsultation', async(req,res) => {

  try{
    const consultationData = req.body;

    // Log the contents of the JSON file landbot has sent
    console.log('JSON Package sent from Landbot:', consultationData);

    // Identify the location of the "users" firestore collection
    const firestore = admin.firestore();
    const usersCollection = firestore.collection('users');

    // Extract userid and make a variable out of userid and another out of the remaining consultation data
    const {userid, ...consultation} = consultationData;

    // Check if users collection contains a document with the specified userid
    const userDocRef = usersCollection.doc(userid);
    const userDocSnapshot = await userDocRef.get();

    if (userDocSnapshot.exists) {

      // If the user id doc exists, add the remaining consultation data as a map field
      await userDocRef.update({consultation: consultationData});
      console.log('Added consultation data to user collection document:', );

    } else {

      // If user id doc doesn't exist, show error message
      console.log('There is no document in the users collection with that userid');
      res.status(422).send('No user exists with this userid');
    }
  } catch(error) {

    //handle errors using logs and sending error responses to landbot
    console.error('Error uploading consultation data');
    res.status(500).send('Error uploading consultation data to firestore');
  }
});

// Register onRequest handler
exports.uploadConsultation = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is the curl request:

```
curl -X POST "http://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/uploadConsultation" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email": "xxx@gmail.com","userid": "ofAkmWfs73OlRLvlsZ5m9nC1t5t1","answers": {"@me_minime": "Me","@hair_challenges": "Dry hair, Breakage","@current_state_of_hair": "Natural","@curl_type": "Type 4C","@retailer": "Uche"}}'
```

I’ve checked all the obvious things and have hit a wall as to what to do next. The url I’m hitting is copy-pasted exactly from my terminal so no issues there (blurred the projectID for privacy reasons).

It also doesn’t seem as though I’ve entered the function because nothing is showing up in the logs (one of the first statements in the function is to print a log message). It looks like the url endpoint isn’t being found, versus the 404 error being caused by a problem with the actual code.

I’m not seeing any error messages in my terminal stating that the function hasn’t deployed correctly each time I write the "firebase deploy --only functions" command. In fact, I’ve also already asked firebase to list the live running functions and the uploadConsultation function is listed there.

Any thoughts on what to try next? Could it be an issue with authentication that’s just returning a generic 404 error? Or something else? This is my first time using firebase so have no idea what to do next, or if there was some sort of set up step i missed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you deployed function with an express app that captures the URL path "/uploadConsultation/uploadConsultation".  That's because you named function "uploadConsultation" and the express app is expecting a nested path of "uploadConsultation".

If you want the URL path you provided in the CURL request, your Express app should instead look for the route "/"

```
app.post('/', async(req,res) => { ... })
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much!!!! Omg i was stuck on this for literally FOREVER. You're a life saver <3